# ¿como puedo hacer que cuando seleccione u JFrame al azar lo elimine de la lista?

Tags: jframe

public class formulario {
    public static void main (String[]args){

```
    Nivel3 nvl3 = new Nivel3 ();
    Nivel1 nv11 = new Nivel1();

    //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

public static class Nivel3 {

    public Nivel3() {
           List<JFrame> frames = new ArrayList<>();


   frames.add(new nivel21());
   frames.add(new nivel22());
   frames.add(new nivel23());
   frames.add(new nivel24());
   frames.add(new nivel25());
   frames.add(new nivel26());
   frames.add(new nivel27());
   frames.add(new nivel28());
   frames.add(new nivel29());
   frames.add(new nivel210());
```

Collections.shuffle(frames);``
JFrame selecionado = frames.get(0);
selecionado.setVisible(true);

```
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

java.util.List tiene el método para quitar un elemento de la lista, que en este caso es implementado por java.util.ArrayList.

```
 JFrame seleccionado = frames.get(0);
 frames.remove(seleccionado); // lo quita de la lista.
```